# Computer Randomly freezing under light load to idle

Tags: windows-10, cpu, freeze, bsod, gpu

So I'm at a total loss and can't figure out what's going on.

Sometimes my computer will freeze up under heavy load meaning Pandora, Counter Strike and a bunch of tabs open or sometimes it will just freeze up if I'm listening to Pandora while browsing the web. It can be sporadic and sometimes it won't happen for a day or sometimes it will happen twice in a row or more and I am not able to use my computer for the rest of the day.

This can also happen if I plug in a USB device to case USB.

When I am idling, like reading my textbook in chrome the computer will randomly freeze and make a high pitched sound.

Idle temps are in the teens and at load around 25 for the CPU and 30 at most for the GPU.

My specs:

AMD FX-6300
Gigabyte 970A UD3P
HyperX 8GB x2
Evga 500 Watt
GTX 750 Ti FTW

I do not think it is the Ram because it has passed a Mem test

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I think it could be the processor, because every other part has already been RMA'd
Along with these issues I frequently get a BSOD and this is a fresh windows install on a Samsung SSD. I have already tried re imaging multiple times.

Possible thoughts I'm having are the CPU or motherboard but everything is pretty new.

Comment: I would start with cmd  -> chkdsk C: /f /r  . (Check Disk then performs an analysis of the disk and returns a status message regarding any problems it encounters.) Post results please. Create First a Recovery Point ! Windows Keys + R -> regedit HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class search for USB (Class USB ! ) delete UpperFilters

Comment: @Wiffzack when I used the check disk it returned no errors and the issue still occurs

Comment: There is a free tool made by nirsoft called bluescreenview, id go download it and let it analyze why your computer is freezing.  It turns the cryptic and often useless error messages into easy to understand explanations.

Comment: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html

Comment: In regard to the answer given by justagrump below, he may be onto something.  Do you smell anything that smells like burning electronics?  A high pitched whine from your PSU is common when it is failing.  Do you happen to have another PSU u could switch out and test with?  I can't think of what else would make a sound like you have described other than a system fan.  Check your connections for your CPU heat sink/fan too.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment so sorry about asking questions first.

1. When your computer freezes, do you need a complete reboot?
2. High pitch sound coming from where? The tower or the speakers?

Just off the top of my head, it sounds like you don't have enough power to the system or it's a bad PSU.

The high pitch can actually be coming from the PSU. If it is, bam, you got your answer.

Your GPU and system is on that edge for 500W

Comment: Good call, a PSU does make a high pitched whine when it is dying.

Comment: Look!  You now have the Comment privilege!

Comment: @Scott Yup, I was sitting at 47 lol.

Comment: I was able to fix it I had to replace the CPU